# How can I get the frame data for a call to list.sort()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection, inspect, stack-frame

I'm trying to access the frame information for a particular call to the `list.sort` method, but i am having trouble.

```
import inspect

def calm_pear(x): # compare    
    cur_frame = inspect.currentframe()
    out_frames = inspect.getouterframes(cur_frame)
    print(out_frames[0].function) # prints 'calm_pear'
    print(out_frames[1].function) # prints 'inner'  
    print(out_frames[2].function) # prints 'outer'
    return id(x)

def outer():
    inner()

def inner():
    [0, 1].sort(key=calm_pear)

outer() # call outer
```

The print-out I get is:

```
    calm_pear
    inner
```

However, the call-order is (`outer`, `inner`, `list.sort`, `calm_pear`)

Why isn't `out_frames[1].function` something like `list.sort`?

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort` is written in C. Functions written in C don't get Python stack frames. Python stack frames are only needed to execute code written in Python.

Whatever you were hoping to do by accessing `list.sort`'s nonexistent stack frame, you will have to find some other way to do it.